# Passing Strings with Emojis to FREFunction in Java

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air-native-extension

Short problem definition :
Using Adobe Native Extensions for Android. 
In my ActionScript I have a String that looks like this :

```
var s:String = "☺"; [see image 1]
```

then I call the NE function like this :

```
  [context].doSomethingWithThisString(s);
```

on the Java side my FREFunction has this line :

```
String string = arg1[0].getAsString();
```

At this point I get an error in logcat as follows :

> JNI WARNING: NewStringUTF input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal
>   start byte 0xf0 W/dalvikvm( 8431):              string:
>   '☺' W/dalvikvm( 8431):              in
>   Lcom/adobe/fre/FREObject;.getAsString:()Ljava/lang/String;
>   (NewStringUTF)

It seems that the encoding is incorrect.  I can't find a way to change the way the FREObjects handle String encoding.   Does anyone know of a way to send 
ISO-8859-1  (ActionScript) strings to the FREFunction if they contain unicode characters?